# JavaScript How to allow only one symbol at the begining of string

Tags: javascript, string, events

I would like to allow the users to put only **one** kind of symbol (character) in `input` and only at the **beginning** of string.

Of course on keyDown/keyUp event. I'm looking-for the fastest solution.

Comment: Do you want input like "a" or "aaaa"?

Comment: Matching the string to a regular expression in an input change event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you have an input like

```
<input type="text" id="text">
```

you can use the following code

```
$(function(){

    var alreadyIn = 0;

    var chars = [33, 64, 35]; // Place here the codes for accepted chars (!@#$ etc)

    $("#text").on('keypress', function(e) {

        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);

        if(chars.indexOf(code) != -1) {

            if($(this).caret() != 0){return false;}

            if(alreadyIn){return false;}

            alreadyIn++

        } else {

            if(alreadyIn && $(this).caret() == 0){return false;}
        }

        return true;    

    }).on('keyup', function(e){ // Keyup event to catch backspace and delete

        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);

        if(code == 8 || code == 46) {

            var current = $(this).val();

            var instances = 0;

            chars.forEach(function(char) {

                if(current.search(String.fromCharCode(char)) > -1){instances++;}
            });

            alreadyIn = instances == 0 ? 0 : 1;
        }

    }).bind("cut copy paste", function(e) { // Do not allow cut copy paste in field

        e.preventDefault(); 
    }); 

});
```

EDIT

I've updated the answer. You have to include jquery caret plugin also. You can find it [here](http://plugins.jquery.com/caret/)

Comment: It's works good, but what when I add some text and after I put `!` at the begining?

Comment: @kicaj Final fully tested version. I believe this is what you want!